# Eigenvalues with positive real parts imply instability

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, initial-value-problems, stability-in-odes

Given an autonomous ode $\dot{x}=F(x)$ with $0$ being its equilibrium point, and all eigenvalues of $DF(0)$ have non-zero real parts.

I have learned that if the real parts of eigenvalues are all negative , then the system is asymptotically stable near $0$. Now I guess that if one of the eigenvalues has positive real part then the system is unstable near $0$, but I can't give a proof, can anyone help me?

Many thanks!

Comment: The answer to this lies in the [Hartman-Grobman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartman%E2%80%93Grobman_theorem), like for earlier questions as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3841334/if-dfx-has-a-striclty-positive-eigenvalue, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634502/eigenvalues-useful-for-stability, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221065/general-method-for-determining-stability

Comment: Talking about Eigenvalues means that the system is linear, doesn't it ?

Comment: The problem is clearly unrelated to to Grobman-Hartman theorem, but you can give a simple proof using a slight modification of Gronwall's lemma.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : It is clear that the eigenvalues are of the Jacobian $DF(0)$.

Comment: @JohnB : Please indicate how you will apply the Grönwall lemma. Especially as a saddle point equilibrium has directions that converge towards it and directions that leave from it. The stated assumptions are exactly those of Grobman-Hartman, and my answer shows that it answers the question directly.

Comment: @LutzLehmann: clear if yo want. So the question is about a linear system.

Comment: Both, it is about the original non-linear system and its linearization, the question is how the properties of the linearization translate to the original non-linear problem. To make that possible in a straight-forward way, the assumption that no eigenvalue is on the imaginary axis is necessary.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Please indicate why you believe that it relates to the Gobman-Hartman theorem when it clearly doesn't. Also please either erase or correct your wrong answer.

Comment: @JohnB : Then tell where the answer fails its purpose. If you think that the wikipedia article has the wrong theorem under that name, or rather from my view, the right theorem under the wrong name, that is possible, it happened before. The whole point of the question is if the non-linear system is similar enough to the linear system so that an eigenvalue of the Jacobian with decidedly positive real part, which implies instability in the linear system, also implies instability in the non-linear system. The cited theorem just tells how similar both systems are in the most comprehensive way.

Comment: @LutzLehmann OK, fine, you don't understand it, but that's not my problem.

Answer (score 1):

A proof of this result is given in Prof. Lebovitz's notes on [Ordinary Differential Equations](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Elebovitz/odes.html) Chapter 8, and I paste his proof here.

> **Theorem 8.4.2** Consider the autonomous dynamical system
> \begin{equation}
>  \dot x = Ax + g(x),~~~~x\in\Omega
>  \label{system}
> \end{equation}
> where $\Omega$ is an open region in $\mathbb R^n$ which contains the origin, $g\in C^1(\Omega)$ and $g(x) = o(|x|)$ as $x\rightarrow0$. If one of the eigenvalues of $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ has a positive real part, then the origin is an unstable equilibrium point.

The proof is accomplished by splitting the the eigenvalues of $A$ into positive and negative parts. Let's assume the eigenvalues of $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_{n_1}$ of $A$ have positive real parts, while the remaining eigenvalues $\lambda_{n_1+1},\cdots,\lambda_n$ have non-positive real parts. Let
\begin{equation}
 \sigma = \min\{\Re(\lambda_1),\cdots,\Re(\lambda_{n_1})\}
 >0
\end{equation}
be the lower bound of the real parts of $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_{n_1}$.
Now we apply the similarity transformation $B = P^{-1}AP$ to obtain the Jordan normal form of $A$, which is given in the block form
\begin{equation}
 B = \begin{bmatrix}
  B_1 & 0 \\
  0 & B_2
 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb C^{n\times n}
\end{equation}
and the matrices $B_1\in\mathbb C^{n_1\times n_1}$ and $B_2\in\mathbb C^{(n-n_1)\times(n-n_1)}$ satisfy

- $B_1$ and $B_2$ possess the Jordan structure: eigenvalues appear on the diagonal, and a certain number of constants occur along a secondary diagonal;
- Each eigenvalue of $B_1$ has a
  positive real part whereas no eigenvalue of $B_2$ has a positive real part;
- The constants along the secondary diagonal are
  all equal to $\nu$, which is a fixed positive constant chosen to satisfy $\nu<\sigma/8$.

We make the change of variables $y = P^{-1}x\in D$, where $D:=\{P^{-1}x:x\in\Omega\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb C^n$. Note that the transformation matrix $P\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ may contain complex entries, hence $D$ can be not contained in $\mathbb R^n$. $h(y) = P^{-1} g(Py)$ is then well-defined as a $C^1$ mapping in $D$. We fix a constant $\epsilon_0 < \sigma/8$ and choose $\delta_0>0$ such that
\begin{equation}
 0<|y|<\delta_0\Longrightarrow |h(y)|<\epsilon_0|y|
\end{equation}
The original dynamical system now can be written as
\begin{align*}
 \dot y_1 & = B_1 y_1 + h_1(y) \\ 
 \dot y_2 & = B_2 y_2 + h_2(y)
\end{align*}
Define the norm of $y_1\in\mathbb C^{n_1}$ and $y_2\in\mathbb C^{n-n_1}$ by
\begin{equation}
 R_1 = |y_1| = \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}
 |y^{(i)}|^2
 \bigg)^{\frac12},~~~~
 R_2 = |y_2| = \bigg(\sum_{i=n_1+1}^{n}
 |y^{(i)}|^2
 \bigg)^{\frac12}
\end{equation}
where $y^{(i)}$ denotes the $i$-th entry of $y\in\mathbb C^n$. Then we can verify
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}R_1^2(t) = 
2\Re\bigg\{
\sum_{j,l=1}^{n_1}
B^{(j,l)} \overline{y^{(j)}} y^{(l)} + 
\sum_{j=1}^{n_1} \overline{y^{(j)}} h^{(j)}(y)\bigg\}
\label{dR1}
\end{equation}
In the equation above, we have

- The diagonal part
  \begin{equation}
   2\Re\bigg\{
   \sum_{j=1}^{n_1} B^{(j,l)} |y^{(j)}|^2
   \bigg\} \geqslant 2\sigma \sum_{j=1}^{n_1} |y^{(j)}|^2 = 2\sigma R_1^2
  \end{equation}
- The off-diagonal (secondary diagonal) part
  \begin{align*}
   \bigg|2\Re\bigg\{
    \sum_{j=1}^{n_1-1}
    B^{(j,j+1)} \overline{y^{(j)}}
    y^{(j+1)}
   \bigg\}\bigg| & \leqslant 
   2\sum_{j=1}^{n_1-1}
   |B^{(j,j+1)}||y^{(j)}||y^{(j+1)}| \\
   & \leqslant 2\nu\sum_{j=1}^{n_1} |y^{(j)}|^2 = 2\nu R_1^2
  \end{align*}
- The nonlinear part
  \begin{align*}
   \bigg|
   2\Re\bigg\{
   \sum_{j=1}^{n_1} \overline{y^{(j)}} h^{(j)}(y)
   \bigg\}
   \bigg| & \leqslant 2\sum_{j=1}^{n_1} |y^{(j)}| |h^{(j)}(y)| \\
   & \leqslant 2 |y_1| |h_1(y)| \\
   & \leqslant 2\epsilon_0 R_1 (R_1+R_2)
  \end{align*}

Hence we conclude
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}R_1(t) \geqslant
 (\sigma - \nu -\epsilon_0) R_1 - \epsilon_0 R_2
\end{equation}
In a similar way, we can prove that
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}R_2(t) \leqslant (\nu+\epsilon_0) R_2 + \epsilon R_1
\end{equation}
Putting these together gives
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}(R_1-R_2) \geqslant
 (\sigma - 2\nu - 2\epsilon_0) R_1 - 2\epsilon_0 R_2
\end{equation}
Recall the choices $\nu,\epsilon_0 < \sigma/8$, we have
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}(R_1 - R_2) \geqslant \frac{\sigma}2(R_1-R_2)
\end{equation}
Let's choose the initial data such that $R_1>R_2$ at $t=0$, then the result above yields
\begin{equation}
 \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} (R_1(t)-R_2(t)) = +\infty
\end{equation}
A contradiction to the stability.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two systems of differential equations, the linear system
$$
\dot v=Av
$$
and the non-linear system
$$
\dot x=F(x)
$$
with $F(0)=0$ a stationary point at the origin and $DF(0)=F'(0)=A$ as the Jacobian. If $F$ is sufficiently smooth, say twice differentiable at least, the vector fields look similar close to the origin.

Now if one eigenvalue of $A$ is real and positive, or a conjugate eigenpair has a positive real part, then there are solutions of the linear system that connect the stationary point with infinity moving outwards. The question asks if the non-linear system is similar enough that solutions close-by inherit enough of this divergence to prevent this point from being stable.

The [Hartman-Grobman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartman%E2%80%93Grobman_theorem) answers this in the most comprehensive way (lesser tools may be able to also answer this with more effort) by the claim that there is some diffeomorphism $\Phi$ mapping a neighborhood of the origin in the linear system to a neighborhood of the stationary point of the non-linear system (here also the origin) with $Φ(x)=x+O(|x|^2)$ so that $$x(t)=Φ(e^{At}v_0)$$ is the solution of $$\dot x=F(x)~~\text{ with }~~x_0=Φ(v_0)\iff v_0=Φ^{-1}(x_0)$$ for $x_0$ close to the fixed point $0$ and $t$ small enough.

Now if $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda=\alpha+i\beta$ with positive real part $α$, then there will be an eigenvector $u+iw$ leading to real solutions $e^{αt}(\cos(βt)u-\sin(βt)w)$ for the linear equation and thus
$$
x(t)=Φ(v(t))=Φ\bigl(e^{αt}(\cos(βt)u-\sin(βt)w)\bigr)
$$
(for a real positive eigenvalue just set $β=0$).
Now if you fix some point $x(t_*)$ on this solution that is still inside the range of the diffeomorphism, then the points $x_0=x(t_0)$, $t_0<t_*$ can be selected arbitrarily close to the origin (select $β(t_*-t_0)\in 2\pi\Bbb Z$ to get points on the same ray to the origin). Thus you get initial points arbitrarily close to the origin that have solutions that pass through the same point $x(t_*)$ (relatively) far away from the origin. This is then a contradiction to both definitions of stability and asymptotic stability.